# How are inherited data placed (arranged) in a derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Im inheriting multiple variables from a super class to a base class and I want the class to have all the variables packed in the descending order (largest types are on the top and the smaller types are on the bottom) but since im inheriting a considerable amount of data, I have no clue on arranging them so that the final inherited class will be tightly packed.

Is there any order which the inherited data get packed to the base class or is it randomly placed or does it get aligned before it is being packed to the final base class?

And I also would like to know if inheriting would affect "cache friendly"-ness of an object.

Thank you!

Comment: Since a derived class *is-a* base class, the members of the base class are fixed in their locations.  That way the code that uses the base object doesn't have to be adjusted depending on which derived class was presented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any order which the inherited data get packed to the base class or is it randomly placed or does it get aligned before it is being packed to the final base class?

The order of sub objects in memory is not random. Members that are declared first are before members with same access that are declared later. Order between different access specifier is unspecified. Bases are before members, in order of declaration.

> have no clue on arranging them so that the final inherited class will be tightly packed.

This is essentially a variant of the packing problem. You can find a solution with a backtracking algorithm. Although the problem is computationally hard, you should hopefully not have too many objects for the complexity to get out of hand.